# String To DateFormat Conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there any way I don't have to specify the number of digits in day/month/year?

For e.g 1/2/1991

I want a method which satisfies both 1/2/1991,11/3/1990,12/12/1991

I don't know how many digits will be there in either month, year, or days.

My code is

```
string copy = splittedData[0]  + splittedData[1] + splittedData[2];//date+month+year
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(copy, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateAndTime = datetime;
```

The problem is the number of digits in splitted data array are not known to me and thus the above format "ddMMyyyy" give me exception on some cases.

Comment: How would you parse 1211991? 12/1/1991 or 1/21/1991? Because of this, you need to restrict your input to force 0s or require a separator.

Comment: @user1056466: can't you pass two digit always for month and date?

Comment: i have the value of date month and year saved in different string variable i just dont know how many digits will be there in either day/month/year

Comment: I've now noticed you have day first, which makes my example not "correct" for that, but still: 1111991 -> 1/11/1991 or 11/1/1991 (november 1 or january 11).

Comment: Wait, are you saying you have date, month, and year all in separate strings (*not* what your example shows)?

Comment: format is date/month/year

Comment: "i have the value of date month and year saved in different string variable" -> meaning `var date = "1"; var month = "11"; var year = "1991"`? If this is the case, *please* update your question to show us *real code*.

Comment: @user1056466, if you have day/month/year in different string them concatenate them with a separator and then you can use DateTime Format for parsing

Comment: You can make a string dateCombined = var1 + "/" var2 + "/" + var3; then convert that to a DateTime data type.

Comment: @Habib although in that case, I don't think `InvariantCulture` is D/M/Y.

Comment: @crashmstr, If the date can be concatenated in "d/M/YYYY", then that format can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you updated your question with the code you have, you can concatenate date components with a separator like:

```
string copy = splittedData[0] + "/" + splittedData[1] + "/" + splittedData[2];
```

Later you can do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(copy, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I used the format `"d/M/yyyy"` **with single `d` and `M` which would account for both single/double digit day/month.**

So it will work for dates like:

```
01/01/2013
1/01/2013
22/09/2013
02/9/2013
```

Comment: OP: "I don't know how many digits will be there in either month, year, or days." This works for month and day, but not year.

Comment: Thanks it worked but now it concatenates time after the date how to remove that.More over i am inserting dt to a sql 2008r2 which also has the data type date time and instead of using this  datetime.ToString("d/M/yyyy") the column of sql stil displays time.

Comment: @user1056466 The time fields in a DateTime are non-nullable ints, so there is no way to distinguish between 0-hours and no-time, regardless of the input format you parsed from. So naturally when you convert to string it always includes a time unless you specify a d/m/y-only output format.

Comment: @user1056466, `DateTime` in .Net framework has Time component as well, if you are only interested in `Date` you can use `DateTime.Date` property, it will still have the time, but set to `0:00:00`, you should store the data in Database in `Date` type column if you are only concerned about `Date`, or `DateTime` if you want to store time part as well. Displaying in application is a different thing, you need to format your `DateTime` object in .NET to display only date part,

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have the day month and year then just create a date with the three of them like so;

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

No parsing is necessary. You already have all the fields you want to create the date, and you dont need to put it into a special format to create a date.

If you are not sure the if the input is valid, then wrap the creation in a try/catch block to catch an **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** should it should occur.

Comment: Then you can use "d/M/yyyy" formatting to get the format of date you need.

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is specifically intended to *not* allow what you are asking for. [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will allow it, though.

You say you have the 3 parts as separate strings -- if you insert the `/`'s and parse, it should succeed (InvariantCulture expects the order month-day-year):

```
string datetimeString = string.Join("/", new[] {month, day, year});
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(datetimeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you could convert them to integers and construct a `DateTime` directly:

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month), Convert.ToInt32(day));
```

Answer (score 0):

What @n00b said. You've already got the individual components of the date: why are you globbing them back together just so you can call `DateTime` parsing routines? Just do something like this:

```
private static DateTime StringToDateTime( string year , string month , string day )
{
  int      yyyy = int.Parse(year) ;
  int      mm   = int.Parse(month) ;
  int      dd   = int.Parse(day) ;
  DateTime dt   = new DateTime(yyyy,mm,dd) ;
  return dt ;
}
```

As an added bonus, The above code will probably run faster than `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.ParseExact()`.